# SweetAlert2 - take the user input from textbox and compare it (using queues)

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

this is the context of the problem:
I have a DB that contains users, and every user when signs in for the first time to the website recive a verification code sent to their email to prove that he's the owner of the mail used to signing in. This code is then crypted and saved to DB too, as a user attribute.

I'm trying to use SweetAlert2 to say in the first alert
"user, check the mail we sent to mail@mail.com to confirm your account"
and in the second alert to show a textbox for input where the user inserts the verification code and, if this the same as the one in DB then active your account, otherwise display another SweetAlert2 error saying that the codes don't match.
I'm not sure if I understood SweetAlert2 correctly, i'm new to web programming, however, here's the code I tried to do:
[edit, don't know why it doesn't display the first "if (status)... as a code]

```
if (status) {
    Swal.queue([{
        title: 'Registration success!',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
        text: $("#firstname").val() + ', check the mail we sent to ' + $("#email").val() + ' to confirm your account',
        'type': 'success'
    }])

    Swal.insertQueueStep({
        title: 'Insert the confermation code we sent you via-mail',
        input: 'text'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            const answer = result.value;
            //check
        } else {
            Swal.insertQueueStep({
                title: 'Codes don\'t match',
                'type': 'error'
            })
        }
    })
}
```

doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
     Swal.fire({
    title: "Insert the confermation code we sent you via-mail",
    input: "text",
  }).then((result) => {
    // get DatabaseCode
    if (result == DatabaseCode) {
      //code matched database code
      const answer = result.value;
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Codes don't match",
        icon: "error",
      });
    }
  });
```

Or this

```
Swal.fire({
    text:
      "user, check the mail we sent to mail@mail.com to confirm your account",
    icon: "question",
  }).then(() => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Insert the confermation code we sent you via-mail",
      input: "text",
    }).then((result) => {
      // get DatabaseCode
      if (result == DatabaseCode) {
        //code matched database code
        const answer = result.value;
      } else {
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Codes don't match",
          icon: "error",
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The second works perfectly, but I tried adding another Swal.fire below the "if (result == DatabaseCode)" to show a successful registration message, but the condition never becomes true. For example, I even tried writing "if (result = 150)" and inserting in user input 150, but the statements enters in the else clause and never shows the successful message. Any reason why? Can't really figure it out

Comment: @AndreaFarneti Sorry made a slight mistake just change ```if (result == DatabaseCode)``` to ```if (result.value == Databasecode)```

Comment: @AndreaFarneti Your welcome. Would you mind accepting this answer?